# Multithreading in Mail server (Postfix)

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, posix

I need to perform multithreading on postfix mail server.
I read about ***POSIX multithreading*** but could it be linked to **postfix smtp server** and if yes then how?
System Specification: ubuntu 14.04 LTS and intel core i3.
Is there any other way for multithreading Postfix?

Comment: If you include why you need multithreading that could help others come up with better solutions? What did you read? Edit your question with links to the posts (don't even think about commenting on this comment with that info)? That way we know if we would offer a solutions you already found.

Comment: Postfix can't do that, it is totally incapable to any multithreading.

Comment: Don't edit your post anonymously (if that was you) login and then edit.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I'm reading it seems as though Postfix is inherently single threaded but gives off the appearance of multi-threading through being able to run multiple instances on the same server to essentially achieve the same thing.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.postfix.users/DAcPHrLygAc

A quick walkthrough is available here:

http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html#quick

http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/News/Multithreaded-Mail-Carrier-Postfix-2.6.0

Comment: This is correct. Multithreaded SMTP wouldn't make much sense. Each process is dealing with different data and different clients so what would they be sharing? It would make a platform-dependent change with no apparent benefit.